# Portable vector shift/permutation in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to write a trimmed mean kernel that takes as input a set of frames (~100). I'm thinking of using an insertion sort (of size ~8). This means that I'll need to read one float/ uint/ushort at a time from the input images and compare it against an 8-wide vector, shifting the elements up and inserting the new value at the correct spot (if necessary), with the largest value added to the mean.

I'm having difficulties finding a portable way of shifting the elements in the vector and inserting the new one at the correct spot. I know that AMD GPUs have ds_permute for example, but those are not portable, and I can't figure out a clever way of using arithmetic and relational operators to do it (since those operate only on their lane and AFAIK unaligned vector accesses are UB in OpenCL).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 8 items in your list then you could add some indirection and have an index table uchar[8]. You assign the pre-sorted elements values 0-7. As you perform the sort you don't rearrange those items, instead you insert their indices into the table.

To get the speedup you then need to store each index using 4 bits to that all 8 fit into a 32-bit word. Honestly, I don't think this will be faster in your case though.

```
float elements[8];
uint index_table = 0;
uint sorted_size = 0;

// insert elements[i]
void insert(uint i)
{
    uint temp = index_table
    for (j = 0; j < sorted_size ; ++j)
    {
        if (elements[i] < elements[temp & 0xf])
        {
            // Insert i
            temp = (temp << 4) | i;
            index_table = (index_table & (4 * j - 1)) | (temp << (4 * j));
            return;
        }
        temp >>= 4;
    }

    // Insert at end
    index_table  |= i << 4 * sorted_size ;
}

void insertion_sort()
{
    // We can skip the first iteration since the 1st element is always inserted at the start
    for (sorted_size = 1; sorted_size < 8; ++sorted_size)
    {
        insert(sorted_size);
    }
}

float ith_smallest(uint i)
{
    return elements[(index_table >> 4 * i) & 0xf]; 
}
```

Comment: Umm, no. I have ~100 elements in the list (so no 4-bit indices). I need to sum all but the smallest and largest 8 (that is, sum the 84 middle elements). The point is doing the sort vectorized (and 8-wide float vectors fit pretty well with modern simd units), so that 10k batches of 100 8Mpx images can be stacked in ~10 mins with reasonable hardware.